# Can't insert data into MYSQL from form using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to insert data into MYSQL from HTML form using PHP .When i enter a valid string in the form and submit it redirect as per code to **main.php** btw the entered string is not inserted into MYSQL table.

Here is my code below

HTML

---

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Id" id="userid" name="userid" title="Enter your Roll number">
    <button onclick="validate()" type="submit" id="login-button" name="formSubmit" value="submit">Login</button>

</form>
```

Here is the form validation.

JS

---

```
function validate()
{
    var id=document.getElementById('userid').value;
    if(id=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Please enter User Id";
        setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.replace('index.php');
        }, 2000);
    }
    else
    {
        if(id.length=="10")
        {
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Login Success";
            setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace('main.php');
            }, 2000);
        }
        else
        {   
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Please enter valid User Id";
            setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace('index.php');
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

PHP

---

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("gcet_elib") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users ( uid ) VALUES ('$userid')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        //$msg = "User Created Successfully.";

        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Login Successfull")';
        echo '</script>';

    }

else
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Cant submit this form")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

}

---

[image: This is MYSQL table structure]

---

So please help me to find out the mistake in the code.

Comment: where is your validate() function

Comment: Where is your database connection? - Also, mysql_query requires a database "link" in the statement, see [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - Also! Please note that **mysql is deprecated** and you should consider using mysqli or PDO

Comment: check if your connection to database is successful .

Comment: button tag don't submit the value instead use <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit" />.. and make sure you have a valid database connection...

Comment: Actually looking at your code, it should only say `Cant submit this form` if you do NOT press the submit button. Where are you getting that message?

Comment: @Akshay : Did you try his code on server??

Comment: yeah im using Xampp server @ Subin Thomas

Comment: @Vijay : You see that error on load??

Comment: yes on loading the page itself it shows the error message "Cant submit this form" in alert @Subin Thomas

Comment: @Vijay : Check my answer. Its normal behaviour. Not an error.

Comment: @Vijay In your validate() function you make redirect to main.php or index.php, it is GET request, so you can not handle any POST data, you can send form data with get, or using ajax

Comment: @Vijay my answer improved. your javascript is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this code it alerts like this "Cant submit this form" .

it might be because your form requirements are not met which is to be met as defined in the validate() fucntion. check your javascript validate() function. It might be wrong. So post it as edit, or may be you are not passing the required information to the input fields which is required for validate() to be true.

mysql or php is not the problem right now as your form is not even submitted.

your script might be wrong
check this see the comments i have put and give a thinking.

```
function validate()
        {
            var id=document.getElementById('userid').value;
            //if id is null this will rise
            if(id=="")
            {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Please enter User Id";
                setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.replace('index.php');
                }, 2000);
            }
            //if the id is not null this means a string is passed
            else
            {
                //if the id is exactly 10 characters long
                if(id.length=="10")
                {
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Login Success";
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace('main.php');
                    }, 2000);
                }
                //if the id is not null and character length is not equal to 10
                else
                {   
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Please enter valid User Id";
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace('index.php');
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this case if the id is not null or null it will redirect `window.location.replace('index.php');` to index.php all the time which is btw meaning even if a string is passed to it or not it will refresh. So correct these conditional statements as you prefer to make it work

Comment: When i enter a valid string the page is navigating to main.php as said in JS btw the value is not inserted into MYSQL table

Comment: Yeah i wanted to redirect the page to index.php if the string is invalid,and it redirects to main.php if the string is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing that error on load, its normal, because you didn't set
 a  `$_POST['formSubmit']`  so that `if` loop will redirect to `else` and error will be shown.

On loading page, you don't have a post variable set, but the php part will execute and it will find `isset($_POST['formSubmit'])` as `false`, and it will go `else` statement.

Make the following changes.

1. In JS, do all the validations and let JS submit the form.
2. Make complete php code inside if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']), so that php code will execute only after the submit done.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.Can you explain me clearly how to correct the code.

Comment: @Vijay : We are not clear what all you are trying to do from this codes.

Comment: Hey thanks for reporting about confusion in my question .I changed it now can you try again.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your html with following:

```html
<form class="form" action="main.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="User Id" id="userid" name="userid" title="Enter your Roll number">
  <button onclick="return validate()" type="submit" id="login-button" name="formSubmit" value="submit">Login</button>

</form>
```

Replace you javascript with following:

```js
function validate() {
  var id = document.getElementById('userid').value;
  if (id == "") {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Please enter User Id";
    return false;
  } else {
    if (id.length == "10") {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Login Success";
      return true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Please enter valid User Id";
      return false;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it btw its not working and its not redirecting to main.php .Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: put a semi-colon after `<button onclick="return validate();` and replace the code `if (id.length == "10") {` with  `if (id.length == 10) {`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Change your php code a bit like below :

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("stackov") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
      {

        $userid = $_POST['userid'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO users ( id ) VALUES ('$userid')";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if($result){
            //$msg = "User Created Successfully.";

            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Login Successfull")';
            echo '</script>';

        }
        else{
          echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cant submit this form")';
            echo '</script>';
      }
      }
```

I have just changed the postion of else block so the message cant submit form will not pop up.

Comment: My actual problem was the data is not getting inserted into MYSQL table btw not that pop up i just used to spot the error.Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Vijay You should clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want no error when page loading, change PHP file as:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("stackov") or die(mysql_error());

  if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
  {

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users ( uid ) VALUES ('$userid')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        //$msg = "User Created Successfully.";

        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Login Successfull")';
        echo '</script>';

    }
    else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Cant submit this form")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Move else statement on check isset($_POST)

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear previously ,i changed it now can you check it again .Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I know your mean. Did you try my change on PHP file?
It may help you anyway.

Comment: Sorry,my actual problem was the data is not getting inserted into MYSQL table btw not that alert msg i just used to spot the error.Thanks for your try.

Answer (score 0):

You are just redirecting and changing window location . you need to submit form . you need to provide action  as `action="main.php"` and in validation if you field is not empty or correct according to your validation just use this `$( "#formid" ).submit();` jquery function.You form will be submitted and and you will be able to access post values in main.php